# Querying special character sensitive

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with special characters in my database. They now display correct, but sql seems to ignore them in queries. For example, unfortunately I have these entries:

`Morgait`
`Morgaít`
`Mórgait`

Now these names had a UNIQUE key, and while trying to add the second and third after the first one, it would already break saying that the last 2 couldn't be added since the name would no longer be unique. In short, í gets treated as a normal i, and ó as a normal o.

When I query:
`SELECT * FROM member WHERE charname = 'Morgait'`
I get all 3 as result. Same for when I change the i to í, o to ó or even both at the same time.

How can I make the database see these differences? I have the collation of the table set to ascii_general_ci (also tried UTF 8 unicode ci).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those collations are `accent insensitive`. You can try `utf8_bin` which is `accent sensitive`, however it's also `case sensitive`.
With accent insensitive collations, for example `é` equals `e` or `ë` and so on.

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE charname = 'Morgait' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

should do the trick. If you need case insensitivity, you can try

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE LOWER(charname) = LOWER('Morgait') COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there really no collation that is both accent sensitive and case insensitive?

Comment: Gee, dates from 2006 and still no fix.. Thanks for the answer anyway!

As for the case sensitivity, I'll fix that by saving it all lowercase and transforming form input to lowercase, then show it the right way on the website..